# Scrollable Listview in sidebar flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Default Sidebar but getting error while scroll

```
'The $controllerForError is currently attached to more than one '
            'ScrollPosition.',
```

here is Sidebar Widget

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/bgimage.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                '${store.user['name']}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
              ),
              Lottie.asset(
                'assets/lottie/coin.json',
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
              ),
              Text(
                '${store.user['wallet']}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/home');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined),
          title: Text('Loss/Profit'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
          title: Text('Results'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/result');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
          title: Text('Referrals'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
       
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Using in homepage

```
drawer: Drawer(
   child: Sidebar(),
),
```

where is scroll position is using multiple

Answer (score 0):

by default drawer is already scrollable. i think the cause of not being able to scroll is not in the drawer